# NoClickDelay.destroy() method or "How to remove the NoClickDelay() function"

Tags: javascript, mobile, dom-events, touch-event

As far as I can tell, [Spinelli's NoClickDelay JS library](http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone) offers no way to 'undo' its functionality.

For example:

```
var a = new NoClickDelay('body');
console.log(a)
//returns NoClickDelay

delete a;
console.log(a)
//still returns NoClickDelay

a = null;
//a is now empty, but NoClickDelay still exists
```

I know I could unbind the `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove` and `onTouchEnd` events, but how can I remove the instantiated `new NoClickDelay()` from memory and the DOM?

Comment: Have you tried using the delete keyword? `delete NoClickDelay;`

Comment: I don't want to remove the whole prototype because multiple instances of the class are called throughout the page, and (as added code above explains), any variable-stored instance still appears to exist after `delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var Obj = {};
Obj.a = new NoClickDelay('body');
console.log(a);
delete Obj.a;
console.log(a);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/euATH/1/

You cannot delete variables.

> delete y;       // returns false (delete doesn't affect variable
>   names)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

**EDIT:**
In terms of removing the event listener, try adding this function and run it

```
function undoNoClickDelay(el) {
    if( window.Touch ) {
            el.removeEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
            el.removeEventListener('touchmove', this, false);
            el.removeEventListener('touchend', this, false);
            delete Obj.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar. This does remove the `a` but the functionality of the `NoClickDelay` still persists.

Comment: So it appears the best way is to simply undo each of its commands one-by-one, and store the object in a deletable object. Nice work.

Comment: Could just do removeEventListeners() I believe to remove all, but not sure if you're binding other events to those elements. (on body, probably will be)